# Why is my hex conversion function off by one?

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn c and am confused why my hex to int conversion function returns a value that is off by one.

Note: 0XAAAA == 46390

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned int hex_to_int(char hex[4]);

int main()
{
    char hex[4] = "AAAA";

    unsigned int result = hex_to_int(hex);
    printf("%d 0X%X\n", result, result);
    return 0;
}    

unsigned int hex_to_int(char input[4])
{
    unsigned int sum, i, exponent;

    for(i = 0, exponent = 3; i < 4; i++, exponent--) {
        unsigned int n = (int)input[i] - 55;
        n *= pow(16, exponent);
        sum += n;
    }   
    return sum;
}
```

Output:

```
46391 0XAAAB
```

---

Update: I now realize "- 55" is ridiculous, I was going off memory from seeing this:

```
if (input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')
    val = input[i] - 48;
else if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'f')
    val = input[i] - 87;
else if (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'F')
    val = input[i] - 55;
```

Comment: Why are you subtracting 55, shouldn't it be `'0'`?

Comment: Also, `x` isn't big enough to store `"AAAA"` You forgot to account for `'\0'`

Comment: The "ASCII hex" to decimal conversion doesn't make any sense.

Comment: the 55 could be -'A'+10, but that means the code does not work for digits 0-9

Comment: @CinCout - `'0'` won't work either - the characters used for hex are non-contiguous in the ASCII character set.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth agreed

Comment: Unless you are working in the field of code golf or obfuscated C challenges, please give variables (and functions) proper names.

Comment: Also note: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22677415/1025391 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187224/1025391

Comment: Undefined behavior as well since `sum` not initialized to zero.

Comment: It is off by one because of `pow`, probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several bugs such as the string not getting null terminated, and the ASCII to decimal conversion being nonsense (value 55?), you don't initialize `sum` and so on. Just do this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char x[] = "AAAA";

  unsigned int sum = strtoul(x, NULL, 16);
  printf("%d 0X%X\n", sum, sum);
  return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT

If you insist on doing this manually:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

unsigned int hexstr_to_uint(const char* str);

int main()
{
  char x[] = "AAAA";

  unsigned int sum = hexstr_to_uint (x);
  printf("%d 0X%X\n", sum, sum);
  return 0;
}    

unsigned int hexstr_to_uint(const char* str)
{
  unsigned int sum = 0;

  for(; *str != '\0'; str++)
  {
    sum *= 16;
    if(isdigit(*str))
    {
      sum += *str - '0';
    }
    else
    {
      char digit = toupper(*str);
      _Static_assert('Z'-'A'==25, "Trash systems not supported.");
      if(digit >= 'A' && digit <= 'F')
      {
        sum += digit - 'A' + 0xA;
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't answer how the logic can be corrected to achieve the requirement.

Comment: There it is, thank you! Not sure where I got 55 from, just shooting from the hip really. It worked for single character hex values.

Comment: @JoshuaBradley Well, it works for upper case digits above 9. This is 6 out of 22 possible characters.

Comment: Maybe you should mention the UB in OP's code and make this a complete answer. I will delete mine then.

Comment: Also, thank you for the char pointer example, I had been wondering about that. It's worlds better than hard coded limits as @CinCout pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You're just making up logic, there isn't a single value you can subtract from a hexadecimal digit character to convert it into the corresponding number.

If you want to be portable, all that C requires is that the symbols `0` through `9` are consecutive in their encoding. There's no such guarantee for the letters `A` through `F`.

Also involving `pow()` which is a double-precision floating point function in this low-level integer work, is a bit jarring. The typical way to do this is by multiplication or bitwise shifting.

If you're hell-bent on doing the conversion yourself, I usually do something like this:

```
unsigned int hex2int(const char *a)
{
  unsigned int v = 0;
  while(isxdigit((unsigned int) *a))
  {
    v *= 16;
    if(isdigit((unsigned int) *a))
      v += *a - '0';
    else
    {
      const char highs[] = "abcdef";
      const char * const h = strchr(highs, tolower(*a));
      v += 10 + (unsigned int) (h - highs);
    }
    ++a;
  }
  return v;
}
```

The above is a bit verbose, you can for instance fold the decimal digits into the string used for the letters too, I just tried to be clear. The above should work for any valid C character set encoding, not just ASCII (and it's less passive-aggressive than @Lundin's code, hih :).